# Possible FindBugs false positive of UL_UNRELEASED_LOCK_EXCEPTION_PATH?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, findbugs

I have code like this:

```
public class Thingy {
  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private boolean shutdown;
  public void shutdown() {
    lock.lock();
    shutdown = true;
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

And FindBugs complains that "Thingy.shutdown() does not release lock on all exception paths" and that I should wrap the `shutdown = true;` line in a try-finally, but as far as I can see there is no way that this can go bad.

Am I wrong or is this a false-positive?

Comment: It seems like Firebug will complain about that unless you use the idiom they specify in their Bug Descriptions, encasing unlock in a finally block. They don't seem to care how simple your code is in the lock block.

Comment: better question, why not just use the try/finally block?  that way when the code gets refactored in the future and becomes more than a trivial assignment, you won't have a bug.

Comment: @jtahlborn but that question is boring :) sure I'll add the try-finally, but I still want to know whether it is truly needed, and if so, why.

Comment: got it.  so this is more like "can simple assignment in java possibly throw an exception"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be fair, it's generally fairly tricky (without being a full-on compiler and doing the analysis) to determine whether any given piece of code can throw an exception or not.

But I agree, in this case, it's a false positive. And even if it isn't - even if there's some dark corner of the JLS/JVM spec that says an assignment can, somehow, through an exception - if you get into that state, you've got more to worry about than an un-released lock!

Answer (score 2):

Its true, but so is the fact that using a lock here is the wrong thing. You only need `volatile`.

In fact you don't even need that as you never read the value, so you can elide the variable and the lock altogether.

Point being that for a simple write, findbugs warning something is probably correct, it just is warning the wrong thing.

Comment: My example is perhaps overly simple.

Comment: Supposedly the `shutdown` is used somehow, but if it is used to initiate orderly shutdown of your service, `volatile` is indeed probably a better fit.